# Does bluetooth low energy device support the same interface with classic bluetooth?

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I want to implement a bluetooth app for bluetooth earphones, and they will communicate with each other via RfcommSocket(AT command).

I use createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord method to create a new RfcommSocket and get its outputstream and inputstream to do write and read.

But if the devices only support bluetooth low energy(BLE), is the way still available without any program changed? Or I also need to implement GATT programs?

Answer (score 0):

There's no RFCOMM for BLE.  If it's a BLE only device then you'll likely have to implement something with GATT.  Many devices support both BLE and "regular" Bluetooth, though.